# How to play .mp3 files in chrome with computer local file

Tags: javascript

I have made a mp3 player. Which plays only src determined files.
But I need it should also play those .mp3 file which is in my computer local drive. But only this c://fakepath... stop my effort.

Can anybody solve this problem. So that I can solve such problem for my next video player.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Local files [can't be referenced from the web](https://superuser.com/questions/224500/display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol). However if you have the file on your computer and access it with file://something, it should be able to access relative urls.

Comment: Sorry, for more clarification, a simple question. How can I play computer local .mp3 file from browser through "input type='file'" through javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168129/5303092).

You can choose a file with input tag and play it with audio tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to Use `Javascript`

Get your audio element and call the play():

```
document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
```

Check example: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html.
[This](http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LCA_MM_AVProc2011/#slide1) site has complete details.

Comment: Sorry, for more clarification, a simple question. How can I play computer local .mp3 file from browser through "input type='file'" through javascript. :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you could try something like:

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="file://my/dir/file.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<a href="javascript:play_sound();">test audio</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function play_sound() {
    document.getElementById('myaudio').play();
  }

</script>
```